# Is it possible to host a WCF service in an Azure WebRole (MVC)

Tags: azure, wcf, azure-web-roles

Is it possible to host a WCF service in an Azure WebRole (MVC)?

Also; I assume that net.tcp is not supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And you're correct that net.tcp won't work in a web role (where all input endpoints have to be HTTP).  But net.tcp should work fine in a *worker* role.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

It's often a little easier to host your WCF services in a web project. Especially when you have multiple WCF Services.