# What is the meaning of Role in Windows azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, cloud

I am just not getting a feel about the meaning of Role in Windows Azure.

There are two roles - Web Role (that has IIS Enabled) and Worker Role (Without IIS).

What does Role mean?

Comment: One question at a time. Not really sure what your question concerning virtual machines is even asking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Windows Azure : What are web role , worker role and VM role?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118942/in-windows-azure-what-are-web-role-worker-role-and-vm-role)

Comment: @Win I just wanted to know what is role mean not specific to WEb/worker role.In general actually.

Comment: @loop My apologies. I removed my downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Mark Russinovich, **Roles** are like **DLLs** in the service process.

You can watch [Mark Russinovich -Introduction to Windows Azure: the cloud operating system](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/BUILD2011/SAC-852F). The video is quite old; I watched it a few years back.

Skip to 21:30 of Video.

[image]