# What is Web Role and Worker Role in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services

What is Webrole and Worker role in Azure? Why should i use web role websites in Azure?(Please try to use lame man terms im not so technical)?
Please kindly try to explain with exampless

Comment: First: Cloud Services (web/worker role) are documented on the Azure site, and should be the first place of reading. Second: I posted a very detailed answer to another question about differences between web Sites vs Web roles - I marked this question as duplicate of the other question, and you should look at what I posted there. There are many other questions covering web/worker roles, as that technology has been around since 2009. You're brand new to StackOverflow, so my advice is to do a quick search first.

Comment: In fact, here's another answer I posted, describing exactly what Web and Worker roles are - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7121886/272109 - I probably could have closed your question as a duplicate of this one as well...