# Engage Azure Worker Role Background Service In Win Form

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles

I have created a new winforms application. I am attempting to Create a class that listens to a storage queue for messages.

```
 using System;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime;
using System.Configuration;

namespace PMonitor
{
         public class QueueWorker : RoleEntryPoint
    {

        public override void Run()
        {
               CloudQueue queue = clnt.GetQueueReference("stuff");

        while (true)
        {
            CloudQueueMessage qMessage = null;

            do
            {
                qMessage = queue.GetMessage(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                if (qMessage != null)
                {
                   //handle message
                }
            }
            while (qMessage != null);


            Thread.Sleep(10000);     
            }
        }

        public override bool OnStart()
        {

            return base.OnStart();
        }

    }

}
```

How do I engage the worker to start running  in the Form to run and tell me when it finds a message in the queue?

Currently instantiating this class and calling Run() in the Form Load locks up the form.

What is the pattern for doing this?

Comment: I'm curious to know why you want to use a worker role in your WinForm application. Would you mind describing your use case?

Comment: All I am trying to do is handle a message when this code see one on the queue. If I call this class in the form load it locks up the Form. I must need an async pattern to get a message so the form doesnt lock up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there's a basic misunderstanding about worker roles. These are not services that you instantiate like a class. Rather, these are definitions for stateless virtual machines that run in Azure. The code snippet you posted is the skeleton code that gets run after a worker role instance (a VM) is booted up, with code (such as queue consumption, in your case) running within the `Run()` method.

A WinForms application have zero need for `RoleEntryPoint` classes, since they are exclusively used within the stateless VM's running in Azure.

Queue processing (or any other tasks you might need to run) have no ties to worker roles; your app can consume queue messages just by working with the storage SDK (or by calling the REST API directly). How/where you set up your queue-processing logic is completely up to you.

Note: You can certainly call services running within worker role instances, from your WinForms application, but I don't think that's what you're asking.

There are several answers on StackOverflow which go into more detail about worker roles, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7121886/272109).

Comment: All I am trying to do is handle a message when this code see one on the queue. If I call this class in the form load it locks up the Form. I must need an async pattern to get a message so the form doesnt lock up?

Comment: I don't think you're understanding what I explained. You cannot use the code you're trying to use locally in your desktop application. You cannot call that class from your form load, regardless whether you use async.