# how to host restApi webservices and SQL server in Azure

Tags: sql-server, web-services, azure

I wanted to host my restApi webservices and SQL Server for the database on Azure. But I am not getting sure which way should i use to run it on Azure ? what is the significant difference between worker role and web role of webservices?

Comment: Can you provide more information about your requirements?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941488/what-is-the-difference-between-an-azure-web-site-and-an-azure-web-role/10941526#10941526) I posted, long ago, about differences between web/worker roles and web sites. As far as what you should use? Completely up to you. (for SQL Server, you'll need  VM though, unless you use SQL Database Service).

Comment: I also specifically answer the difference between Web Role and Worker Role, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118942/in-windows-azure-what-are-web-role-worker-role-and-vm-role/7121886#7121886). (somewhat dated, as you'll see mention of the now-extinct VM Role, but you'll be able to glean basic diffs in web and worker role)

Answer (score -1):

i would suggest

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-rest-service-aspnet-api-sql-database

This provides details about the restapi webservices deployment on Azure.

regards,
Raghu Ariga